# How does this sed command： "sed -e :a -e '$d;N;2,10ba' -e 'P;D' " work?

Tags: sed

I saw a sed command to delete the last 10 rows of data:

```
 sed -e :a -e '$d;N;2,10ba' -e 'P;D'
```

But I don't understand how it works. Can someone explain it for me?

**UPDATE:**

Here is my understanding of this command:

1. The first script indicates that a label “`a`” is defined.
2. The second script indicates that it first determines whether the
   line currently reading pattern space is the last line. If it is,
   execute the "`d`" command to delete it and restart the next cycle; if
   not, skip the "`d`" command; then execute "`N`" command: append a new
   line from the input file to the pattern space, and then execute
   "`2,10ba`": if the line currently reading the pattern space is a line
   in the 2nd to 10th lines, jump to label "`a`".
3. The third script indicates that if the line currently read into
   pattern space is not a line from line 2 to line 10, first execute "`P`" command: the first line
   in pattern space is printed, and then execute "`D`" command: the first line in pattern
   space is deleted.

My understanding of "`$d`" is that "`d`" will be executed when sed reads the last line into the **pattern space**. But it seems that every time "`ba`" is executed, "`d`" will be executed, regardless of Whether the current line read into **pattern space** is the last line. why?

Comment: Please ask more specifically about the part which is unclear, by explaining as much as possible yourself. As is, your question basically asks for a tutorial.

Comment: Did you RTFM or look at any resurces? There are some good ones, like http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html ...

Comment: Check my updated answer. The `d` is really executed just once, but it removes the whole pattern space which can hold up to 10 lines.

Comment: I understand,@choroba, your explanation is clear., thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:a` is a label. `$` in the address means the last line, `d` means *delete*. `N` stands for *append the next line into the pattern space*. `2,10` means lines 2 to 10, `b` means *branch* (i.e. *goto*), `P` prints the first line from the pattern space, `D` is like `d` but operates on the pattern space if possible.

In other words, you create a sliding window of the size 10. Each line is stored into it, and once it has 10 lines, lines start to get printed from the top of it. Every time a line is printed, the current line is stored in the sliding window at the bottom. When the last line gets printed, the sliding window is deleted, which removes the last 10 lines.

You can modify the commands to see what's getting deleted (`()`), stored (`<>`), and printed by the `P` (`[]`):

```
$ printf '%s\n'  {1..20} | \
    sed -e ':a ${s/^/(/;s/$/)/;p;d};s/^/</;s/$/>/;N;2,10ba;s/^/[/;s/$/]/;P;D'
[<<<<<<<<<<1>
[<2>
[<3>
[<4>
[<5>
[<6>
[<7>
[<8>
[<9>
[<10>
(11]>
12]>
13]>
14]>
15]>
16]>
17]>
18]>
19]>
20])
```

Comment: If the line currently reading into the pattern space is not the last line, is `d` not being executed?

Comment: `D` deletes what `P` prints and if the pattern space is empty behaves like `d` otherwise it does not read another line into the pattern space but continues as if it has i.e. it goes to the first sed command. Basically it 'pops' a line off the front of the pattern space.

Answer (score 0):

a simpler resort, if your data in 'd' file by gnu sed,

```
sed -Ez 's/(.*\n)(.*\n){10}$/\1/' d

                         ^
```

pointed `10` is number of last line to remove

just move the brace group to invert, ie. to get only the last 10 lines

```
sed -Ez 's/.*\n((.*\n){10})$/\1/' d
```

Comment: what means `\1` ?